# Why won't Dell Studio 1749 load Windows anymore?

Tags: windows, boot

My daughters Dell Studio doesn't load Windows anymore.  After the Dell page it sits there doing nothing. I've tried the Set Up and Boot option pages, I can set Default configuration, but can't get the option to reset to Factory Default settings.  Hardware & Memory tests pass OK.  Any ideas how I can restore to Factory settings?

Comment: F11 at the Dell logo screen at boot should load the Dell recovery options

Comment: F11 or Alt F11 don't do anything.  The only way I can step out of the Dell logo window is through F2 or F12.  I can't get to the recovery options.

Comment: All I can suggest is to contact Dell for a Recovery DVD. http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/media